# Set font icon to UILabel from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I have my own fontIcon list in the project. I have added it to my plist. When I try the following code it works correctly:

```
myLabel.text = @"\uE100"; 
//This is my font icon code
```

But when I try to get the font icon code from another string it wont work.

```
NSString* theFont = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\u%@",@"E100"];
myLabel.text = thefont;
```

Is there any special type for icons? what should I do to get the font icon from my API?

Comment: your font file should be in app local, you can find so tutorial on "how to add custom font in ios app over google."

Comment: you can't split up the \uE100 like that.  I don't know where you are storing or creating E100, but it is at the point that you create a string @"\uE100"

Comment: @pawan my .tff file is added to my project

Comment: @JonRose I'am getting the icon title from my api, I tried to get the whole string like @"\uE100" but it still doesn't work

Comment: I've use https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit/tree/master/FontAwesomeKit and have been impressed with how they organized there code to solve the same problem (displaying icons in text using a custom font).  Perhaps looking over their code could help you. Or you can make a custom subclass of `FAKIcon` which does most of this work for you.

Comment: @Niloufar did you get any help from my answer, if so then please upvote and accept it as answer.

Comment: @Niloufar did you get any help from my answer or should i remove it?

Comment: @pawan thanks but it doesn't work

Comment: @Niloufar okay, i have deleted my answer. but the fact is you can seperate a unicode charater in two part & merge them later on. If you find any solution, please post it here as well.